# How can I update an interval of dates in the database (Hibernate HQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, hibernate, hql

Consider, for some specific database entry of id `id`, an interval of dates in the database, from `BEGIN_DATE` to `END_DATE`, denoted by (`BEGIN_DATE`,`END_DATE`).

Given two new dates, that form the interval (`newBeginDate`, `newEndDate`), I must update (`BEGIN_DATE`,`END_DATE`) so that the resulting interval contains all 4 dates. In other words, I want to **add the two intervals** (And since I am adding them, the resulting interval may remain the same or grow, but never shrink).

**A few examples:**

If (`BEGIN_DATE`,`END_DATE`) = (`January 10`,`January 20`), then:

- (`BEGIN_DATE`,`END_DATE`) + (`Jan 15`,`Jan 25`) = (`Jan 10`,`Jan 25`)
- (`BEGIN_DATE`,`END_DATE`) + (`Jan 05`,`Jan 15`) = (`Jan 05`,`Jan 20`)
- (`BEGIN_DATE`,`END_DATE`) + (`Jan 05`,`Jan 25`) = (`Jan 05`,`Jan 25`)
- (`BEGIN_DATE`,`END_DATE`) + (`Jan 15`,`Jan 15`) = (`Jan 10`,`Jan 20`)
- (`BEGIN_DATE`,`END_DATE`) + (`Jan 10`,`Jan 13`) = (`Jan 10`,`Jan 20`)

The two following queries together achieve this goal. The first one updates `BEGIN_DATE`, and the second updates `END_DATE`:

```
session.createQuery(
   "update APPOINTMENTS " +
     "set BEGIN_DATE = :newBeginDate " +
     "where " +
     "(BEGIN_DATE is null or BEGIN_DATE > :newBeginDate) " +
     "and ID = :id ")
           .setParameter("newBeginDate", newBeginDate)
           .setParameter("id", id)
           .executeUpdate();

session.createQuery(
   "update APPOINTMENTS " +
     "set END_DATE = :newEndDate " +
     "where " +
     "(END_DATE is null or END_DATE < :newEndDate) " +
     "and ID = :id ")
        .setParameter("newEndDate", newEndDate)
        .setParameter("id", id)
        .executeUpdate();
```

My question is: 
**How can I do it in a single query?**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL and SqlServer, but this is so basic I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: Why are you using two statements for that? You can do it in a single `UPDATE` And what exactly do you mean with "grow, not shrink"? Please  **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't know how to do it in a single UPDATE, that's exactly my question.

Comment: Done, Mr. Horse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is limited when it comes to more complex programming constructs, so since you use Hibernate I would just read the appointment entity instance and update its fields. That would require two queries, one to read and one to update, but still it would be only one update statement and is the most readable solution.

If you still want only one update statement and nothing else, your two statements could be merged into one by using `case`:

```
update APPOINTMENTS 
set BEGIN_DATE = case when (BEGIN_DATE is null or BEGIN_DATE > :newBeginDate) then :newBeginDate else BEGIN_DATE end,
    END_DATE = case when (END_DATE is null or END_DATE < :newEndDate) then :newEndDate else END_DATE end
where (BEGIN_DATE is null or BEGIN_DATE > :newBeginDate or END_DATE is null or END_DATE < :newEndDate)
    and ID = :id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` functions. For NULLs use `COALESCE()`.

```
update APPOINTMENTS
set BEGIN_DATE = coalesce(least(BEGIN_DATE, :newBeginDate), :newBeginDate),
    END_DATE   = coalesce(greatest(END_DATE, :newEndDate), :newEndDate)
where ID = :id
```

I think LEAST and GREATEST don't need an explanation. COALESCE will pick the new date, if the old one is NULL. So no condition except of `ID = :id` is needed in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Very nice, concise, answer. However, this would update the database even when BEGIN_DATE and END_DATE don't change. I am having lock problems when using InnoDB and many simultaneous threads update APPOINTMENTS simultaneously, so I would like to reduce the number of updates.